# javascript Accordion Customisation

Tags: javascript, accordion

I am using a Javascript accordion function which I found on the internet, however my Javascript skills are at a novice level ( Hence why I sourced a completed version to begin with).

What I have noticed is that when you load the page the accordion shows half initiated ( See Jsfiddle), what I would like to happen is that the accordion appears completely closed when the page is loaded.

I have put the accordion up on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/richlewis14/uPvwL/, unfortunately the level of javascript used is beyond my capabilities and would appreciate any help in modifying it to my requirements, also if anyone could explain what is actually happening in the code I would appreciate that also, I would like to learn rather than jsut get the answer

Thanks

Comment: You mean that `TyNewydd` should be also closed?

Comment: Yes, sorry should have made that a little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script takes an argument to specify which element to open by default.

Change `parentAccordion.init("acc","h3",0,0);` to `parentAccordion.init("acc","h3",0);` and you're good to go :)

See http://jsfiddle.net/uPvwL/2/ for a working example.